# Plane division, binding data to each segment, creating bumps

Tags: three.js, webgl

Is it possible to divide a plane in to several segments such that each segment resembles a data value, that has a scalar value. Based on which, I can create bumps.

Thanks!

Comment: What you described sounds like [heightmaps](http://www.lukaszielinski.de/blog/posts/2014/11/07/webgl-creating-a-landscape-mesh-with-three-dot-js-using-a-png-heightmap/)?

Comment: or simply iterating through the planeGeometry.vertices would do the trick, dont forget to update geometry

Comment: HI, My doubt is if I have a graph with nodes and want to have a 3d bump like thing on a surface for each node, then how to create a height map first. Firstly, I am new to this. I have gone through the entire procedure through examples and blogs of terrain creation, but I cannot understand how to convert my graph of nodes to a height map. @wendelbsilva pailhead

Comment: @KeerthikaKoka You will have to find a way to map your graph into the plane. Ofcourse, depending on this map you may lose some information about your graph. For example, if you create a 2d view of your graph and map into the plane, you can use [Delaunay Triangulation](http://christophermanning.org/projects/voronoi-diagram-with-force-directed-nodes-and-delaunay-links/) to generate the 2D mesh. Later, you can use the node data value to change height (turn it 3D). Unfortunately, in this 'mapping' I described we lose the information about the connections between the nodes.

Comment: hI, Thankyou so much, I would work on it and post questions if any.

Comment: I have already created a force layout graph , now is it possible that i take the coordinates of the nodes for positioning and create bumps in 3d.

Comment: Hi, I now have a json data with nodes and links typically used for force layout d3.js, each node has an overall trust value in the json. based on this is there any way to generate a height map for generating a terrain in 3d.